# How to fire "change" event in codemirror plugin for ckeditor 4.3?

Tags: ckeditor, codemirror

I'm usign CKEditor to update the content of an iframe. Everytime the user changes something in CKEditor its reflected on the iframe. I'm using the change event to update the content. Here's my code:

```
var editor=CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
editor.on('change', function(e) {
    $(#iframeContainer).contents().find('.contentText').html(editor.getData());
});
```

Everytime I type something or change the font color, style, size, etc. It works as it's suppose to be and the CKEditor content is cloned into the iframe. But when I switch to source view using the codemirror plugin, all changes made in source view won't trigger the change event. Is there any way to trigger the change event from the "source view" generated by codemirror?

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror doesn't auto-sync the textarea it was created from. But it does fire its own [change event](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_change), and you could handle this, debounce it, and either sync the textarea content (call the `save()` method on the CodeMirror instance to do this), or directly get the current content by calling `getValue()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you have any idea in how to access the CodeMirror instance? I tried window["codemirror_" + editor.id].refresh(); but it returns _undefined_

Answer (score 0):

```
var cm = ... // some CodeMirror instance

cm.setValue("new value");
cm.refresh();
```

Comment: You should also add some text and explain what you are doing. Code alone might seem confusing to some